# call jquery script after file upload finished asp.net mvc 2

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

i am trying to display a jquery popup after a fileupload action? not sure how to code this?

```
 <%= Html.BeginForm("Upload","Home",FormMethod.Post,new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }) %>
<%{ %>


<input type="file" id="upload" name="upload" />

<button id="btnUpload">
    upload</button>



<%} %>

 <script type="text/javascript">

    function SayFinished() {
        alert('Finished');
    }
 </script>

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload()
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase selectedFile = Request.Files["upload"];

        if (selectedFile.ContentLength > 0 )
        {
            //do some processing call jquery script to open popup: SayFinished()
        }

        return View("Index");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to return a view from your controller after the post that has an onload script.

On the new view, put the following javascript:

In the controller set the following after file uploaded

```
ViewData["FileUploaded"] = "true";
```

Then in the view set

```
<% if (!String.IsnullOrEmpty(ViewData["FileUploaded"]) && ViewData["FileUploaded"] == "true") { %>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            SayFinished();
        });

        function SayFinished() {
            alert('Finished');
        }
     </script>
<%} %>
```

Comment: what i want to stay on the same page?

Comment: See above for same page solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this plugins to upload file using jQuery, [http://pixelcone.com/jquery/ajax-file-upload-script](http://pixelcone.com/jquery/ajax-file-upload-script/)

Sorry for previous feedback with incorrect information.

Comment: You can't post files through ajax as far as I know. Only using a flash plugin or other "fake" does it appear to be ajax.

Comment: Based on @Gats 's advice, I remove the jQuery.ajax() method in the answer. You can use this plugins to upload file using jQuery, http://pixelcone.com/jquery/ajax-file-upload-script/

Comment: Post still uses ajax. It's the XmltHttp.. javascript object that can't post. The plugins use flash or something else to post the file.